# How to get dynamic property in Velocity Template

Tags: java, velocity

I'm facing a difficult problem when I am coding with Velocity Template.

```
#set($key = "")
```

$key is a dynamic variable.

So when I want to get the property of another variable which has property is $key. What will I do?

```
#set($temp = #evaluate("$data.$key");
```

or

```
#set($temp = $data.$key);
```

All of them is not valid.
Please help me!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the passed string is evaluated in two steps, you need to escape the first dollar (with a backslash) and the quotes (by doubling them) at the first step. You would do:

```
#set($temp = "#evaluate(""\$data.$key"")")
```

Answer (score 0):

To access other velocity variable's property you just need to address it as `$variableName.propertyName`. see [velocity properties](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#properties). in your case:

```
#set($temp = $data.key);
```

I don't know of such built-in reflection capabilities, even
[ClassTool](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/ClassTool.html) of velocity tools support reflection but not allowing executing:

> It was not designed with reflective execution of code in mind and thus provides no facilities for code execution, nor direct access to the actual methods

Comment: Thanks for helping.
But as I told, propertyName is dynamic, so I want to access a dynamic property. Can you help me?

Comment: I updated my answer. I don't know on any  velocity's built in option

Comment: @Nguyễn Dương for invoking a method dynamically in java  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string

Comment: Thank you for your support. I found the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get()`:

```
#set( $temp = $data.get($key) )
```